# Sorting and outputting in another file

Tags: text-processing, files, sort

How can I sort a file and output it to a newly created file?

Let's say I have `Names.txt` containing a list of names. I want to reverse sort `Names.txt`; create a new file called `SortedNames.txt`; and output the sort to the newly created file; ideally, these should be done in a single statement.

Answer (score 4):

To sort `Names.txt` in a reverse sort order and output it into `SortedNames.txt`:

```
sort -r Names.txt > SortedNames.txt
```

The file `SortedNames.txt` does not have to exist. If it does exist and you have write-permission to that file, the command above will overwrite its contents.

The [sort](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) command has many more options.